# Section Sign when displaying .txt in Browser?

Tags: browser, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following issue: We have a tool that saves some data to a .txt and this data is delimited by §. This data can be accessed through the webservers directory index and viewed in the browser. 
But both FF and Chrome will not display the § character correctly, and when copy / pasting data it will not copy the correct char as well. 
The whole thing works fine though, when using Ctrl + S, the file is set as UTF-8 and the character is displayed in a proper way in any text editor.

The file is correctly encoded as UTF-8, the Content-Type header I get is text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Should I be mistaken and § not be printable in UTF-8 (why would the text editor show it correctly then), please make a suggestion for a proper charset to use, while keeping in mind that we might also have Chinese / Japanese characters etc. in our data.

Thanks for your help.

P.S. by not being diplayed correctly, i mean the black diamond with the ? in it.

Comment: `§` may not be used literally in an otherwise UTF8-encoded file. The differences you see between programs is because they choose to show *something*, rather than crashing or displaying an error. Bottom line: if your file "is" UTF8, this is invalid. If you need this exact separator, then "the file" (viewed as a whole) is not valid UTF8 (but individual sections may be).

Comment: Ok thanks, would you have a suggestion on another encoding to use, or is there no intersection between § and chinese characters as well?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  How is § encoded in the file?  It is a valid Unicode character and its UTF-8 representation is [0xC2 0xA7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A7/index.htm) but if you represent it by something else which is not valid UTF-8 (say, its Latin-1 representation 0xA7) then you'd get the symptoms you describe, except the file will most emphatically not be valid UTF-8.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, I did not know a Unicode-Variant of that Character did exist.. probably it's simply missing the 0xC2 part then, I will check it in hex, thanks for your help :)